# How do I get the address of the connected wallet with web3modal?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, web3js

I'm building an application with next.js and web3. To connect the user wallet to the front-end I'm using web3modal as following:

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const [signer, setSigner] = useState<JsonRpcSigner | null>(null)

  async function connect() {
    const web3Modal = new Web3Modal()
    const connection = await web3Modal.connect()
    const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(connection)
    const signer = provider.getSigner()

    setSigner(signer)
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <button onClick={() => connect()}>Connect wallet</button>
      { signer && (
        <h3>wallet connected: {signer._address}</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The user can successfully connect the wallet, unfortunately `signer._address` is always null. I'd like to display to the user with address has just been connected, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

This is not a question about web3Modal, but a question about ethers.

You can get the address like this:

```js
const [address, setAddress] = useState()
// ...
setAddress(await signer.getAddress())
```

The documentation is here: https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-getaddress

Answer (score 0):

`provider.getSigner()` returns a promise.

You should use await to get the actual address

```
const signer = provider.getSigner();
const address = await signer.getAddress();
setAddress(address);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the address using the following

```
const account=(await provider.listAccounts())[0]
```